# How to group and select document corresponding to max within each group in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, max, aggregation-framework

Here is my mongo collection 'sales':

```
{"title":"Foo", "hash": 17, "num_sold": 49, 
"place": "ABC"}

{"title":"Bar", "hash": 18, "num_sold": 55, 
"place": "CDF"}

{"title":"Baz", "hash": 17, "num_sold": 55,
"place": "JKN"}

{"title":"Spam", "hash": 17, "num_sold": 20,
"place": "ZSD"}

{"title":"Eggs", "hash": 18, "num_sold": 20, 
"place": "ZDF"}
```

I would like to group by hash and return document with the greatest "num_sold". So as output I would like to see:

```
{"title":"Baz", "hash": 17, "num_sold": 55,
    "place": "JKN"}

 {"title":"Bar", "hash": 18, "num_sold": 55, 
    "place": "CDF"}
```

I know basic of aggregate operator and here is how I would group and get maximum of num_sold, but I need whole document corresponding to maximum, not just the value.

```
db.getCollection('sales').aggregate([
{$group: {_id: "$hash", max_sold : {$max: '$value'}}}
])
```

In SQL I would have done it with join, but in mongo. I also read that in mongo group and sort do not work well together.

Comment: What version of `mongodb` are you using?

Comment: @BatScream 3.0.4. I am still researching my question and it looks like it is possible to sort within a group on client side, but I don't understand the difference between server and client side. Also seems like I can accomplish the same with mapreduce, but not yet clear how.

Comment: The expensive `$sort` and `$group` approach can be avoided. Please see my answer below to get it done on the server side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) stage to accomplish this. It avoids the usage of [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and then again doing a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) or an [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).

- `$group` by `_id` and get the maximum `max_num_sold` for each group, accumulate all the documents in the group using the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/push/) operator.
- `$redact` into sub documents per group, keeping only those which have the maximum `max_num_sold` in their `num_sold`

*sample code:*

```
db.getCollection('sales').aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":"$hash",
         "max_num_sold":{$max:"$num_sold"},
         "records":{$push:"$$ROOT"}}},
{$redact:{$cond:[{$eq:[{$ifNull:["$num_sold","$$ROOT.max_num_sold"]},
                       "$$ROOT.max_num_sold"]},
                "$$DESCEND","$$PRUNE"]}},
])
```

*test data:*

```
db.getCollection('sales').insert([
{"title":"Foo","hash":17,"num_sold":49,"place":"ABC"},
{"title":"Bar","hash":18,"num_sold":55,"place":"CDF"},
{"title":"Baz","hash":17,"num_sold":55,"place":"JKN"},
{"title":"Spam","hash":17,"num_sold":20,"place":"ZSD"},
{"title":"Eggs","hash":18,"num_sold":20,"place":"ZDF"}
])
```

*test result:*

```
{
        "_id" : 18,
        "max_num_sold" : 55,
        "records" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("567874f2b506fc2193a22696"),
                        "title" : "Bar",
                        "hash" : 18,
                        "num_sold" : 55,
                        "place" : "CDF"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 17,
        "max_num_sold" : 55,
        "records" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("567874f2b506fc2193a22697"),
                        "title" : "Baz",
                        "hash" : 17,
                        "num_sold" : 55,
                        "place" : "JKN"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! It took me awhile to understand. This is very creative use of aggregation framework. Do you know what it means to do something on serve side or on client side? I want to fully research the question and try it with map reduce also.

Comment: Yes but you do a costly operation that is $sort. But then again there are always ways of doing it. I gave you a different approach to do it:)

Comment: Sorry, I posted alternative solution with costly sort and group separately for better readability.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like grouping in mongodb does not distort the order and something like this is possible:

[mongodb, how to aggregate with group by and sort correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899409/mongodb-how-to-aggregate-with-group-by-and-sort-correctly?rq=1).

In particular, for the above example we can get the following:

```
db.getCollection('sales').aggregate([
{$sort: {"num_sold":-1}},
{$group:{"_id": "$hash",
         "max_num_sold" : {$first:"$num_sold"},
         "title":{$first: "$title"},
         "place":{$first:"$place"}
         }}
])
```

Here is output:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 17.0000000000000000,
            "max_num_sold" : 55.0000000000000000,
            "title" : "Baz",
            "place" : "JKN"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 18.0000000000000000,
            "max_num_sold" : 55.0000000000000000,
            "title" : "Bar",
            "place" : "CDF"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```